# Javascript passing extra argument into a callback

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass in extra argument to a function that has a callback in parameter, to no avail

```
function loadMapService() {
  
      service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

      service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
    }
  }
}



function callback(results, status) {
  // do something 
}
```

I want to be able to pass something else into the function `callback`when I execute the following function with the callback is parameter

```
service.nearbySearch(request, callback, somethingElse);


function callback(results, status, newArgument?) {
  //how to pass in the new argument properly and retrieve it?
}
```

Comment: Instead of using callbacks, why not `Promise` instead?

Comment: You cannot make the Google code do something it doesn't already do. You *can* create a function with that "new argument" value available by using a closure.

Answer (score 0):

Using a closure makes it pretty easy.

```
const myAdditionalParamter = 1;
service.nearbySearch(request,(results, status) =>
{
     // use myAdditionalParamter here;
});
```